# Convert IPython notebook JSON to Python code programatically

Tags: nbconvert

I have JSON format of an IPython notebook in memory. I would like to convert this into python code. Can i use nbconvert for this?

I tried something like the following but it does not work.  I guess the JSON isn't really in the expected NotebookNode object format.

```
nbconvert.PythonExporter().from_notebook_node(JSON)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right, nbconvert doesn't accepts JSON (or dict) to convest, so you need to convert to NotebookNode, using a code like:

```
import nbformat
mynotebooknode = nbformat.reads(your_json_in_memory, as_version=4)
```

and use the code nbconvert that you posted to transform in a python file:

```
nbconvert.PythonExporter().from_notebook_node(mynotebooknode)
```

Ps: I don't know why, but a lot of funcs uses 's' at the end for represent memory and not a file, like:
json.dump(file) -> json.dumps(str_in_memory)
json.load(file) -> json.loads(str_in_memory)
And that the case here